# change 2 select joined query to fill with zeros/null instead of filtering out when data does not exist in one query

Tags: sql

I have the code below that queries the same table for the value of 2 different tags, and display them side by side (2 columns) when their time stamps match. This has been working ok. However, in some rare cases, the value for 1 of the tags may not be recorded on the db, leaving both SELECT results with different lengths, at which point my WHERE clause at the end filters one of the rows out (the one that does not have a match on table B).

If the entry exist on the db, they will always have the same time stamp so comparing them works. But sometimes one does not exist because my archiver program only writes to the db if there is a change in that value from last time it was reported, and if it doesn't change or by coincidence it is the same as before, it will not write to SQL, so the value with new ts will not exist.

```
SELECT A.[TIME_STAMP], A.[Value1], B.[Value2]
FROM (SELECT TIME_STAMP
      ,TAG
      ,CAST(DESCRIPTION1 AS float) AS 'Value1'
    FROM [dbo].[MAINLOG]
    WHERE TAG LIKE '%01%Day%') A
cross JOIN (SELECT TIME_STAMP
      ,TAG
      ,CAST(DESCRIPTION1 AS float) AS 'Value2'
    FROM [dbo].[MAINLOG]
    WHERE TAG LIKE '%02%Day%') B
WHERE A.TIME_STAMP = B.TIME_STAMP
ORDER BY A.TIME_STAMP
```

This is what the result looks like:

```
TIME_STAMP                 Value1  Value2
2019-10-19 08:19:05.000    0       0
2019-10-19 08:50:40.153    1.5     1
2019-10-19 09:03:39.107    2       2
2019-10-19 09:04:15.113    3.5     2.5
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to modify the query to :

1) match the results of the 2 queries by time stamp and display them in 2 columns, side-by-size; AND

2) if SELECT query A and B yield a table of different length (e.g. result B is missing one value), show the missing value as zero / null for that entry.

thanks.

Comment: Please show us your entire query. The one you have put in your question starts with the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t realize it got cut. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These subqueriers just make things overly complicated. I think that you can simply self-`LEFT JOIN` the table as follows:

```
SELECT
    A.TIME_STAMP,
    CAST(A.DESCRIPTION1 AS float) AS 'Value1',
    COALESCE(CAST(B.DESCRIPTION1 AS float), 0) AS 'Value2'
FROM
    [dbo].[MAINLOG] A
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MAINLOG] B ON A.TIME_STAMP = B.TIME_STAMP AND B.TAG LIKE '%02%Day%'
WHERE A.TAG LIKE '%01%Day%'
ORDER BY A.TIME_STAMP
```

One important thing is that you all conditions on the `LEFT JOIN`ed table must belong to the `ON` clause of the join. Do not put them in the `WHERE` clause, else they become mandatory, which results in non-matched records being filtered out.

It also occurs to me like you *might* just be able to solve this using conditional aggregation. This is not *exactly* what you asked for, but it could be worth giving it a try and see if it comes close to your expected results:

```
SELECT
    TIME_STAMP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TAG LIKE '%01%Day%' THEN CAST(DESCRIPTION1 AS float) END) AS 'Value1',
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN TAG LIKE '%02%Day%' THEN CAST(DESCRIPTION1 AS float) END) 0) AS 'Value2'
FROM [dbo].[MAINLOG]
WHERE TAG LIKE '%01%Day%' OR TAG LIKE '%02%Day%'
GROUP BY TIME_STAMP
ORDER BY TIME_STAMP
```

Comment: GMB, this worked very well. The 2nd proposed solution actually accounts for different order of tags (i.e. on the first if you swap 02 and 01 tag names the results are different), so I will use it for a while to see how it performs. Really appreciate your help. -ps; a comma is missing after ```END)``` on the 4th line, but it is a quick fix. thx again

Comment: Welcome @user.tm! Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need only a LEFT join -

```
SELECT A.TIME_STAMP, A.Value1, B.Value2
FROM (SELECT TIME_STAMP
      ,TAG
      ,CAST(DESCRIPTION1 AS float) AS 'Value1'
    FROM [dbo].[MAINLOG]
    WHERE TAG LIKE '%01%Day%') A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TIME_STAMP
      ,TAG
      ,CAST(DESCRIPTION1 AS float) AS 'Value2'
    FROM [dbo].[MAINLOG]
    WHERE TAG LIKE '%02%Day%') B
WHERE A.TIME_STAMP = B.TIME_STAMP
ORDER BY A.TIME_STAMP
```